# Плавное изменение иконки при нажатии

Tags: jquery, button, icon

Есть кнопка, внутри кнопки иконка (набор font-awesome, bars - это гамбургер-меню, times - крестик)

```
<button id="main-btn">
  <span id="menu-icon" class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></span>
</button>
```

Есть такой код js (оставил только те строки, которые связаны с кнопкой, поэтому код может казаться неоптимальным/некрасивым):

```
var growth = false;
var get = function(obj) {
  return document.getElementById(obj)
};
get('main-btn').onclick = function() {
  if (growth) {
    $('#menu-icon').removeClass('fa-times');
    $('#menu-icon').addClass('fa-bars');
    growth = false
  } else {
    $('#menu-icon').removeClass('fa-bars');
    $('#menu-icon').addClass('fa-times');
    growth = true
  }
}
```

Работает как и написано - при нажатии убирает значок меню, добавляет крестик. При повторном нажатии - убирает крестик, добавляет значок меню.

Все бы хорошо, только хотелось бы красивой смены этих самых значков. Пример [сайта](https://www.ljosleidarinn.is/) (хотя наверное и в ру сегменте таких полно, но этот под рукой был). Кнопка meira: при нажатии бургер-меню красиво складывается в крестик. Конечно, конкретно эта анимация необязательна, но я сам  принцип работы понять не могу.

Если есть возможность написать пример в рамках того кода, который я привел (то есть существует флаг, в зависимости от его значения выполняются строки кода вида "айди.действие"), то буду премного благодарен. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Там сделано так: есть `span` с `border-top`, а также `:before` и `:after` тоже с `border-top`... при нажатии происходит анимация........ `:before` и `:after` наклоняются на 45 градусов, образуя межлу собой угол в 90, а `span` убирается из виду......... то есть там не обходится простой сменой картинки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

```
$('#menu-icon').fadeIn(3000, function() {
   $('#menu-icon').removeClass('fa-times');
   $('#menu-icon').addClass('fa-bars').fadeOut(3000);
});
```

Вот остальные примеры JQuery эффектов. Например, animate... http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/